# HTML Mailto Subject

Tags: email, html, email2case

I am working with HTML templates in Service Cloud and I want to embed buttons into the body of the email we are sending out for quick replies by the customer. In order for the customer reply to link with the case when it comes back, it must have the 'Case Thread ID' in the subject and/or the body of the reply. Is there a way to code the mailto link on the button so that it pulls this into the reply subject line from the original email we send out?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specifying an email address, you can also add a subject & a body to mailto links.  You can see some generic examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507387/mailto-body-formatting).

Below check out an example that adds a **Case Thread Id** to the subject of the mailto link.

```
Sample <A HREF="mailto:email@domain.com?subject=Contact%20Support%20{!Case.Thread_Id}">Link</A>
```

Comment: Hi Jack, I've tried this but it just displays to merge tag and not the actual thread id? So my outgoing email from Salesforce does display the thread ID but my button (with a mailto link in) or mailto link doesn't pull it through in the reply from the customer if they use it?

Comment: So here's my subject line in the outgoing email to the customer: Please Read: Lower Data Limit Alert - {{{Case.Thread_Id}}} and this works fine. Here's the mailto code that doesn't for the reply from the customer: href="mailto:email@emailaddress.co.uk?subject=I'd%20like%20to%20buy%20more%20data%20please%20-%20{{{Case.Thread_Id}}}

Comment: Hi Jack, I've cracked it - it was user error!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @HalfPipe